# Is it possible to implement GCM (google cloud messaging) without maintaining any own server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement GCM (google cloud messaging) in my app.
I want the functionality of sharing an image and two parameters along with them between two users of that same app.
but I wont be able to implement server or wont be able to maintain it so Is it possible to implement GCM without maintaining any own server.
without maintaining any own server means no need to code outside the app in eclipse.

Comment: Due to what's written in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565301/can-gcm-be-used-to-send-and-receive-messages-between-android-devices), you should use some kind of server for using GCM. However, what Tarun Varshney suggested might be easiest for you.

Comment: without maintaining any own server means?for posting images and parameters you are using webservices for that we need server,so please explain in more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want GCM to be implement without any maintenance of server. Then you can look forward to cloud solution like [parse.com](https://parse.com/) or [Bluemix](https://ace.ng.bluemix.net/) . These are very easy to handle.

Comment: I checked with these links, They are going to manage everything for me. But they have some limitations and pricing. So how can I conclude which one is better for my purpose

Comment: you should use parse.com. They are giving 30req/sec free

Comment: Will try to implement, If it worked than very good otherwise will ask you again. N yes thanks for this help. Is there any sample code available for this ?

Comment: I am not getting the settings for push notifications from user to user on parse.com can you just help me out.